# ICD 10 dropdown for a Spring application with mysql database in the background

Tags: javascript, mysql, spring, icd

I am currently working on a Spring healthcare application where the doctor can enter the diagnosis codes in the input tag of a page. What I want is that the doctor should be able to select the codes from a drop-down menu, the problem with ICD10 codes records is that there are a lot of them. Can anyone suggest a tool or a javascript library that can make my life easier?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a search feature for this. You could have a text input with a search button. When the user types some of the initial text of the ICD-10 code and clicks the search, you perform a search request to the backend, and with the results, you can load a regular select.

Of course you would have to create a search endpoint in your backend, and possibly your select would need to be paginated. You could even display the results in a table instead of a select and add a select button to the rows.

If you just want to display the codes in your HTML, the resulting page will be heavy, no matter how many pagination features you add. If all your ICD-10 codes are sent to the client right away, we could be talking about MBs to render your page, that's why I'll move the retrieval of codes to the backend and limit it there with some "limit + offset" feature.

So, a search box. When the user clicks the search button, you perform a request telling the backend the term to search, a limit, like 10, and an initial offset, probably 0. You display those results in a table and, if there are more, a pagination. When the user clicks another page, you perform the same request specifying a different offset, and so on.